PHP and HTML: what is this invisible special characters detected by PHP but not possible to clean, created by translate.google

translate text with: https://translate.google.com
translated but generates special characters i have never seen before.

NOT visible with "inspect elements"

and NOT possible to clean with:
$entry = preg_replace( '/[^a-z0-9 ]/i', '', $entry );

result given by translate.google

visible by: onlinephp.io/

PHP detected not allowed characters by
!preg_match("/^[_a-zA-Z0-9-@. ]+$/", $entry)

What is this? I am confused.
re-create the issue:
https://translate.google.com/?hl=de&sl=de&tl=en&text=zur%20besseren%20Vorstellungen%20wie%20ein%20Bild%20bei%20Nutzung%20aussehen%20k%C3%B6nnte&op=translate

These are appearances of Zero-Width Space Wikipedia. And you can delete with this code $string = preg_replace('/[\x{200B}-\x{200D}\x{FEFF}]/u', '', $string);

thank you. But why is preg_replace( '/[^a-z0-9 ]/i', '', $entry ); not working too? Thank you.

"and NOT possible to clean with: $entry = preg_replace( '/[^a-z0-9 ]/i', '', $entry );" That is not true.

gre_gor is right.
The not simplified code for stackoverflow as original is:
$entry=preg_replace('/[^-a-z0-9_ßüÜöÖäÄÃŸÃœÃ¼Ã–Ã¶Ã„Ã¤_@:., ]/i', '', $entry);

EDIT: original and not for stackoverflow simplified code to replace the string is:
$entry=preg_replace('/[^-a-z0-9_ßüÜöÖäÄÃŸÃœÃ¼Ã–Ã¶Ã„Ã¤_@:\.\, ]/i', '', $entry); 

and in my question i used this simplified code:
$entry = preg_replace( '/[^a-z0-9 ]/i', '', $entry );

That should do it, as gre_gor commented.
So the problem is the not-simplified preg_replace above.
Solved.
Thank you.
